# Python Functions with multiple arguments

Tags: python, function, dictionary, apply

I have written the following code

```
def createv(dsn,vname,benchdsn,benchvar):
    #global grp
    for t in range(len(dsn)):
        w=dsn[vname].iloc[t]
        #print(w)
        for index in range(len(benchdsn)):
            #print(index)
            z = benchdsn[benchvar].iloc[index]
            #print(z)
            if w <= z:
                grp = z
                print(grp)
                break     
            else:
                continue
    return grp

recent_sample['carvaluegrp2']= createv(recent_sample,'CarValue',df6,'carvalueU')
```

The issue is that for the newly created variable carvaluegrp2, all values are the same - which is the last value of CarValue from recent_sample. I tried to use map() and apply() functions, but I am getting syntax errors. All I want is to have appropriate value - which the function is returning for each record of CarValue - as a value in the variable carvaluegrp2.

Comment: your `else` is indented wrong

Comment: Thanks Ahmad. I checked that now, the value of grp from the print statement is coming out to be fine. The issue is mapping these values against each record in the data frame for the new variable. There I am getting only the last value repeated for all records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append your result to a running list like this:

```
def createv(dsn,vname,benchdsn,benchvar):
    result = []
    for t in range(len(dsn)):
        w=dsn[vname].iloc[t]
        #print(w)
        for index in range(len(benchdsn)):
            #print(index)
            z = benchdsn[benchvar].iloc[index]
            #print(z)
            if w <= z:
                grp = z
                print(grp)
                break     
            result.append(grp)
    return result
```

Also, you never need `else: continue`. It's the same as having the if statement without an else.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I used your recommendation and am getting the following error:
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: I can't see your data, so I can't write a solution, but your output needs to be the same length as the number of rows in the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I just changed your recommendation a bit and it worked! I actually moved the result.append(grp) statement before the break statement.